# Pascal input way

Tags: pascal

I'm a beginner and for the moment i'm enjoying competitive programming as a way to learn.
I had this task to input a list of words and output it crypted.
My algorithm went fine but my problem was in the way I input the list of names.
I don't know if i can put the link of the problem, but i have to input this once :

```
4
word
localization
internationalization
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

and get this result

```
word
l10n
i18n
p43s
```

But the only was i managed it is by giving the names one by one, is there a way to input everything once without considering it one solide string?

here is my script :

```
program A71;
uses wincrt;
var
    word: String;

function correctname(word : String): Boolean;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
    correctname:= true;
    for i:=1 to length(word) do 
        if not (upcase(word[i]) in ['A'..'Z']) then
            correctname:= false;        
end;

function Cryptname(var word : String): String;
var 
    wordcrypt: String;

begin
    wordcrypt:= '';
    str(length(word) - 2, wordcrypt);
    Cryptname:= word[1] + wordcrypt + word[length(word)];
end;        

begin
    repeat
        repeat
            readln(word);
        until correctname(word);

        if correctname(word) and (length(word) > 10) then   
            writeln(Cryptname(word))
            //writeln(word);
        else
            writeln(word);
        //readkey();
    until false;        
end.
```

**Update : **

```
program A71;
uses wincrt;
type
    tab = array[1..100] of String;
var
    word: tab;
    correctwords,n, i : Integer;

function correctname(word : tab; correctwords : Integer): Boolean;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
    correctname:= true;
    i:= 0;
    //for i:=1 to length(word[correctwords]) do 
    repeat 
        i:=i+1;
        if not (upcase(word[correctwords][i]) in ['A'..'Z']) then
            correctname:= false;
    until not correctname or (i = length(word[correctwords]));          
end;

procedure Cryptname(var word : tab; correctwords : Integer);
var 
    wordcrypt: String;

begin
    //wordcrypt:= '';
    str(length(word[correctwords]) - 2, wordcrypt);
    word[correctwords]:= word[correctwords][1] + wordcrypt + word[correctwords][length(word)];
end;        

begin
    correctwords:=0;
    readln(n);
    repeat
        readln(word[correctwords]);
        if correctname(word, correctwords) then
            correctwords:= correctwords+1;
    until correctwords = n;

    for i:= 1 to correctwords do
    begin
            if correctname(word, correctwords) and (length(word[correctwords]) > 10) then
            begin
                Cryptname(word, correctwords);
                writeln(word[correctwords]);
            end 
        else    
            writeln(word[correctwords]);
    end;
    readkey();      
end.
```

Now my code crashes directly at the second input.

Update, I relsolved it this way :

```
program A71;
uses wincrt;
type
    tab = array[1..100] of String;
var
    word: tab;
    correctwords,n, i : Integer;
    tester : String;

function correctname(tester : String): Boolean;
var
    i : Integer;
begin
    correctname:= true;
    i:= 0;
    //for i:=1 to length(word[correctwords]) do 
    repeat 
        i:=i+1;
        if not (upcase(tester[i]) in ['A'..'Z']) then
            correctname:= false;
    until not correctname or (i = length(tester));          
end;

procedure Cryptname(var wordcrypt : String);
var
    wordcryptaux: String;
begin
    wordcryptaux:= wordcrypt;
    str(length(wordcrypt) - 2, wordcrypt);
    wordcrypt:= wordcryptaux[1] + wordcrypt + wordcryptaux[length(wordcryptaux)];
end;        

begin
    correctwords:=0;
    readln(n);
    repeat
        
        readln(tester);
        if correctname(tester) then
            correctwords:= correctwords+1;
            word[correctwords]:= tester;
    until correctwords = n;

    for i:= 1 to correctwords do
    begin
        if correctname(word[i]) and (length(word[i]) > 10) then
            begin
                Cryptname(word[i]);
                writeln(word[i]);
            end 
        else    
            writeln(word[i]);
    end;
    readkey();      
end.
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Is it that you want to be able to press `<Enter>` several times (4) until you are "done"? How would the program know you are done? Always 4 lines? Maybe an empty line at the end?

Comment: By the way, `correctname` checks the word always until the end unnecessarily. You should break the loop once it's false. Is `wordcrypt:= '';` necessary?

Comment: The first input is the number of lines.So it depends on the input, i'll try to make the instruction works in an array and come up with an update. yes, wordcrypt has to be initialized as i get a warning if i don't.

Comment: Research how to turn on range checks for your compiler.  Print the variables in the crashing line just before it, and run it again

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I have resolved it with a simple for loop and an array ( you can see it above ), but can you explain range checks ? I use sublime compiler and a simple FPC package from google. Thanks for your great time both, i don't know how to give you a reputation point, excuse me for that.

Comment: You need to pass -CRriot to the compiler. I don't know how to do that from sublime.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed and improved your code a little bit. Beware your `if` in the main program has only one line, but the indentation makes you think it has two; I also fixed that.

```
program A71;
uses wincrt;
type
    tab = array[1..100] of String;
var
    word: tab;
    correctwords, n, i: Integer;
    tester: String;

function correctname(inputword : String): Boolean;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i:=1 to length(inputword[correctwords]) do
    begin
        if not (upcase(inputword[i]) in ['A'..'Z']) then
            Exit(false);
    end;
    Exit(true);
end;

procedure Cryptname(var wordcrypt : String);
var
    wordcryptaux: String;
begin
    wordcryptaux:= wordcrypt;
    str(length(wordcrypt) - 2, wordcrypt);
    wordcrypt := wordcryptaux[1] + wordcrypt + wordcryptaux[length(wordcryptaux)];
end;

begin
    correctwords:=0;
    readln(n);
    repeat
        readln(tester);
        if correctname(tester) then begin
            Inc(correctwords);
            word[correctwords]:= tester;
        end;
    until correctwords = n;

    for i:=1 to correctwords do
    begin
        if correctname(word[i]) and (length(word[i]) > 10) then
            Cryptname(word[i]);
        writeln(word[i]);
    end;
    readkey();
end.
```